# How to avoid calling toString() when using AutoComplteTextView

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview

I need some help in understanding the issue.
I have a drop down menu represented by AutoCompleteTextView. Any time I choose an option from the menu I set a String to be shown. But the problem is that before the String is shown I see for a second or so my object.toString()
I know that if I change toString  in my object class I get no more problem with that. BUT I need the toString() function to stay as it is without changing. Are there any ways to do that?
My adapter

```
class CustomAdapter(context: Context, @LayoutRes val id: Int, private val items: List<Data>) : ArrayAdapter<Data>(context, id, items) {
    private val inflater by lazy { LayoutInflater.from(context) }

    
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = inflater.inflate(id, null)
        val neededData = items[position].neededData
        val textView = view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.needed_item)
        textView?.text = neededData
        return view!!
    }
}
```

That is how I set the adapter

```
 context?.let { context ->
        dropdown.setAdapter(ClassName.CustomAdapter(
                context = context,
                id = R.layout.item,
                items = viewModel.dataList
        ))

        dropdown.onItemClickListener = createListener()
    }
```

ToString in Object

```
override fun toString() = "Data(" +
        "neededData='$neededData', " +
        "extraData=$extraData, "
        ")"
```

When I choose option in dropdown, for couple of seconds I can see extraData from toString() function, only then neededData is set

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you post your code?

Comment: @m0skit0 I added some code

Answer (score 1):

So, the solution is found.
I just needed to override Filter and convertResultToString(resultValue: Any?): CharSequence in Adapter. Now everything works perfectly